# SUMIF contains one of elements in array (OR)

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs

I have a list of payments where I would like to sum up the costs which description equals to one of the elements in my array.

```
EMTE     € 120,00 
Bread    € 35,24 
Lidl     € 0,89 
Plus     € 5,19 
Aldi     € 2,29 
Jumbo    € 4,70
```

So with an array of `{"Lidl", "Aldi"}`, It would give me the total of (2,29+0,89) 3,18.

I tried `Sum.If`, but I don't seem how to use the `or` statement in it properly and combine it with an array kind of input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) / [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) function in a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) to provide an extra level of cyclic calculation.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, {"Lidl","Aldi"}))
```

[image: Aldi_Lidl]

Comment: You can just use the SUM function as a wrapper here without having to array enter the formula. Only if the {"Lidl", "Aldi"} part of the formula instead referenced a range would you need to use SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pivot table to get the result. The advantage of this solution is that it does not require complex formulas and is easy to change.
To create the pivot table:

- Select your data and use Insert > PivotTable
- Drag your first column to ROW, your second column to VALUES
- Make sure the VALUES are aggregated using a SUM
- In the top row of your PivotTable you see a DropDown that allows you to select the values that should be included in your report
- Make sure a grand total is displayed for all rows